# How to find subgroups of a product group containing the diagonal?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups, direct-product

Given a non-abelian group $G,$ I am curious about subgroups of $G\times G$ containing the diagonal $\{(a, a)\mid a\in G\}.$ As a starting point, I thought of looking at the simplest examples $S_3$ and $D_8$. Direct computations quickly become tedious as the product group is a bit large. Also, I think [Goursat's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma) could be helpful, but don't know how to use it for an explicit calculation.

Hope someone with more experience in group theory can help me to find them for $S_3$ (and if possible $D_8$ and $Q_8$). At least if you can give me a list of all such groups and a hint to find them, that would be great.

Comment: I would suggest you learn to use GAP. That is very useful particularly for calculations involving small groups. For $S_3$ there is only one intermediate subgroup (between the diagonal and the whole group) and it has order $18$. $D_8$ and $Q_8$ are more complicated: in both cases, there are four intermediate subgroups, one of order $16$ and three of order $32$. This problem is difficult in general but there are some easy special cases. If $G$ is nonabelian simple, then the diagonal subgroup is maximal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following observation seems to me useful.

> Let $G$ be a group, $D$ be a diagonal in $G\times G$, $K$ be a normal
> subgroup of $G$. The set $$ H=\{(x,y)\mid x^{-1}y\in K\} \qquad(*) $$
> is a subgroup of the group $G\times G$ and $D<H$.
>
> Inversely, if $D<H<G\times G$ then there exists a normal subgroup $K$
> in $G$ that  $H$ constructs by formula (*).

The first statement is almost obvious. In the second one we have to specify the subgroup $K=\operatorname{gr}\{x\mid (1,x)\in H\}$.